# Хранятся ли логи о загружаемых через браузер файлы?

Tags: администрирование

Может ли Сисадмин в организации узнать какие файлы загружаются через браузер (firefox)? Например, в облачные хранилища и т.д.? Хранятся ли где-то эти логи с названием и объемом файлов, сами файлы? Может ли адимн открыть эти файлы?

Comment: Конечно, как и всю историю и содержимое всех посещенных страниц.

Comment: Получается все загружаемые файлы на облако ещё где-то и сохраняются в системе, чтобы админ мог их открыть? Вы уверены?

Comment: Ну наверное можно и в системе, но зачем ими засорять систему?